# vscode find opened file in files sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut key to go from the currently opened file in editor to the opened file in the files sidebar on the left?

I am editing a file and wanted to find it in the files sidebar on the left. is there a direct way to go to that file in the files sidebar?

Comment: Do you have `Explorer: Auto Reveal` set to `true`?

Comment: This answer is unclear. Please edit it to make it more clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand you, You can us**Ctrl+Shift+E**.

Comment: Does this solve your question?

Comment: your first big reputation 

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with some easy steps in vs code.

1. Click on **Open View..** under the **View** menu (Located at top)
2. Type or find  **Open Editors** and select

Thats it.

And if you want to find or highlight to find the opened file in Side bar and open Editors simply press **Ctrl+Shift+E**